# Cookies not being sent on cross-sub-domain request on an api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, bootstrap-select

I have a page stored on https://page.domain.com.
Here, I'm using javascript (mainly Bootstrap) to get data from https://api.domain.com.
The first call, when the page is loaded, is a "sort of" authentication call which return a cookie in the headers:

```
set-cookie: oauth=emd4YWgybTJobmJnZjVrbXl2ZjdlZThiOzkzczg1YWt2YzNyZW42cjk3M2U4dXlweA==; domain=.domain.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 16 Apr 2021 11:58:07 GMT;
```

I can see in the developer tools (Chrome) that the cookie is stored correctly.

But then, when I make the next api call (example, filling a dropdown list - bootstrap autocomplete ) the cookie is not in the request.
This was working fine when I was building it in localhost (same "domain", I guess) but now, having the html and the apis running on different domains, it seems cookies are not being shared.
I thought it could be because of the two different domains, but according to the documentation, when a cookie is set to the main domain, all sub-domains should be able to share it. (also, I' including the "withCredentials" flag)

This is the code of the initial call (and setting up the subsequent one):

```
    $.ajax({url: 'https://api.domain.com/get-cookie',
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      })
    .done(function (response) {

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker().ajaxSelectPicker({
    ajax: {
      // data source
      url: 'https://api.domain.com/data.json',
      // ajax type
      type: 'GET',
      // data type
      dataType: 'json',
      // Use "{{{q}}}" as a placeholder and Ajax Bootstrap Select will
      // automatically replace it with the value of the search query.
      data: {
        q: '{{{q}}}'
      }
    },
    // function to preprocess JSON data
    preprocessData: function (data) {
      var i, l = data.length, array = [];
      if (l) {
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          array.push($.extend(true, data[i], {
            text : data[i].name,
            value: data[i].code,
            data : {
              subtext: data[i].code
            }
          }));
          localStorage.setItem(data[i].code, data[i].name);
        }
      }
      // You must always return a valid array when processing data. The
      // data argument passed is a clone and cannot be modified directly.
      return array;
    }     
  });
    }
);
```

I'm using AWS API Gateway and Lambda functions, but that should not be relevant...

---

When taking the url from the selectPicker (eg: https://api.domain.com/data.json ) and putting it directly in the browser I see the cookie being sent.
This seems to indicate the issue might be in the Bootstrap Select component that is not sending the headers correctly.
I'm not sure if I can make it work as expected or I have to find some other alternative.

Comment: So in your initial call, you explicitly instruct the browser to send & receive credentials cross-domain - and then in all the following ones, you decided that was not necessary any more?

Comment: _“but according to the documentation, when a cookie is set to the main domain, all sub-domains should be able to share it”_ - that applies to read access on the client, and “normal” requests made by the browser. Cross-_origin_ AJAX requests are a different thing.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , but how do I find a solution then? I know when I was doing this locally it was working. Maybe it has to do with the Cross-origin, as you suggest. How can I make it work? I checked the documentation of Bootstrap-Select and I don't seem to find anything related with cookies, or headers.

Comment: Well it looks like `ajaxSelectPicker` takes very much the same parameters, as `$.ajax` does … so, specify `withCredentials` in there as well?

Comment: It sounds a bit random and guesswork but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to also include the withCredentials on the selector request:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker().ajaxSelectPicker({
    ajax: {
      // data source
      url: 'https://api.domain.com/data.json',
      // ajax type
      type: 'GET',
      // data type
      dataType: 'json',
      // Use "{{{q}}}" as a placeholder and Ajax Bootstrap Select will
      // automatically replace it with the value of the search query.
      data: {
        q: '{{{q}}}'
      },
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    },
    // function to preprocess JSON data
  preprocessData: function (data) {
        // ...
  }     
 });
 }
);
```

Thanks @CBroe for the idea in the comments.